# When I update date from gridview, the date and month will always switch places. I want it to be dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: c#, winforms, date, gridview

I edit and changed the dateentry for the first row from 05/04/2014 to 06/04/2014. After clicking update, it becomes 04/06/2014. My dateEntry column is a date type format and not a datetime format for your information.  I want it to be dd/mm/yyyy format.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**If I put anything higher than 12 in the date. etc 16. will have error.**

[image]

[image]

**Error following @Arshad advice**

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        bindResultGridView();

    }
    //Logout.Visible = false;
    string memName = (String)Session["UserName"];
    lblUsername.Text = String.Concat("Welcome Guest!");

    if (Session["Username"] != null && Session["Username"] != String.Empty)
    {
        lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + memName + "!";


    }

}


private void bindResultGridView()
{
    String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

    try
    {

        String SQL = null;

        SQL = "SELECT BlogID, Name, Blogtype, Description, Dateentry FROM [EntryTable]";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);
        grdBlog.DataSource = dt;
        grdBlog.DataBind();


        reader.Close();
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void grdBlog_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
    bindResultGridView();
}

protected void grdBlog_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdBlog.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindResultGridView();
}
protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
    //  get product id from data key
    int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

    //  get current grid view row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
    //  find text box for txtPrice
    TextBox blogtype = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogType");
    TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox dateentry = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDateEntry");
    //  Remove $ sign
    string strName = name.Text;
    string strBlogType = blogtype.Text;
    string strDescription = description.Text;
    string strDateEntry = dateentry.Text;
    DateTime datDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateEntry, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
    {
        updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, datDate.ToString());
    }

    else
    {

    }
}

private void updateBlogGridviewRecord(int blogid, string strName, string strBlogType, string strDescription, string strDateEntry)
{

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogType", strBlogType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", strDateEntry);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", strDescription);
    myConnect.Open();

    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Record updated!";
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Update fail";
    }

    myConnect.Close();


    //Cancel Edit Mode
    grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
    bindResultGridView();
}
```

Source code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdBlog" runat="server" style=
"margin-left: 0px" Width="695px" Height="147px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        onrowcancelingedit="grdBlog_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="grdBlog_RowEditing" 
                        onrowupdating="grdBlog_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="BlogID" 
                        onrowdeleting="grdBlog_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="True" 
                        onpageindexchanging="grdBlog_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogID" HeaderText="BlogID" 
                                SortExpression="BlogID" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BlogType">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBlogType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateEntry">
   <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEntry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateEntry", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'>
 </asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateEntry", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript : return confirm('Confirm delete this record?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Followed @Chirag Adhvaryu This worked for me.

```
protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
        //  get product id from data key
        int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

    //  get current grid view row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
    //  find text box for txtPrice
    TextBox blogtype = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogType");
    TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox dateentry = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDateEntry");
    //  Remove $ sign
    string strName = name.Text;
    string strBlogType = blogtype.Text;
    string strDescription = description.Text;
    string strDateEntry = dateentry.Text;
    DateTime datDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateEntry, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
    {
        updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, datDate);
    }

    else
    {

    }
}

private void updateBlogGridviewRecord(int blogid, string strName, string strBlogType, string strDescription, DateTime datDate)
{

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogType", strBlogType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", datDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", strDescription);
    myConnect.Open();

    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Record updated!";
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Update fail";
    }

    myConnect.Close();


    //Cancel Edit Mode
    grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
    bindResultGridView();
}
```

Comment: Check this simple program which will help you to understand https://ideone.com/fdWsHB

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' >
     </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I updated my source code above. It still changes places between dd and mm when update!!! @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: If I put anything higher than 12 in the date. etc 16. will have error. I added the image @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: @Jordjmax for that you can validate date using JavaScript OR regex

Comment: Erm wat u mean, i don;t know how. @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: @Jordjmax I post answer of your query regarding Date validation  using Range Validator

Comment: But this doesn't solve my updating problem right? I wan to update successfully without the dd and mm switching places. @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: @Jordjmax I don't understand why you cast string to DateTime when you already get string value while updating??

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW2--M_n7Y0&list=UUmCCdX9I1m4aSr0m50H1Dyg set to hd quality   @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: not getting open video.
"This video is private." @Jordjmax

Comment: Sorry it is now public. @Chirag Adhvaryu

Comment: Now I come to conclusion of your problem is that you set DateEntry as a Date type in your database and while you update the result you pass it as a string.
that give's you a error.
so, change parameter to Datetime instead of string in method updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, datDate);

Comment: @Jordjmax one another conclusion I think is that first check which value store in database in DateEntry column.
if it store yyyy/mm/DD and you pass it as a DD/mm/yyyy then it may also gives you error.
check this scenario also.

Comment: replace `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", datDate);` with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry",datDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));`

Comment: Thanks. I posted the codes that worked above. just making sure that this are the correct codes that u meant right? before I ticked you. And also ya I don't understand why people here at the starting cannot understand, I thought at the starting I already stated it is a date type and not datetime type lol? @Chirag Adhvaryu

Answer (score 0):

Update your `DateEntry` template field with `'<%# Eval("DateEntry", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'` instead of `'<%# Bind("DateEntry") %>'`

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateEntry">
   <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEntry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateEntry", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'>
 </asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateEntry", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Edit**
     string strDate = dateentry.Text;

```
DateTime datDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate , new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))

{
   // Call your update method with 
}
else
{
 //Show validation error message
}
```

Comment: Erm where to put it? I pasted my source code above. I also added a image, there's no format @Arshad

Comment: Sorry, My last answer was for windows application. Please check the updated annser

Comment: I updated my source code above. It still changes places between dd and mm when update!!! @Arshad

Comment: can you change `SQL = "SELECT BlogID, Name, Blogtype, Description, Dateentry FROM [EntryTable]";`

Comment: Updated query above. Still the same thing!! @Arshad

Comment: If I put anything higher than 12 in the date. etc 16. will have error. I added the image @Arshad

Comment: off course, you need to convert it to the date time before sending to the server

Comment: oh how to convert? btw I am using date datatype for dateentry in the database @Arshad

Comment: you need to convert it in the `datetime` before submit it the database

Comment: in the protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) ?? @Arshad

Comment: I added a image. Error. how to convert? @Arshad

Comment: Still got problem. If I change the dd to over 12, it gave me Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Then If I change the dd to 12 or less, it doesn't get update, it doesn't even get update and it doesn't switch places with the mm. Just no effect. I changed code behind and source code to current code above. Is it correct? @Arshad

Comment: I have updated your code in the If block. Please check

Comment: Followed your updated code. Grr the same problem. If I change the dd to over 12, it gave me Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Then If I change the dd to 12 or less, it doesn't get update, it doesn't even get update and it doesn't switch places with the mm. Just no effect.. @Arshad

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW2--M_n7Y0&list=UUmCCdX9I1m4aSr0m50H1Dyg set to hd quality   @Arshad

Answer (score 0):

You can validate Date Time like this on client side.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date">
    <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" MaximumValue="28/12/9999" MinimumValue="28/12/1000" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>'>
                </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
```